# Proper JSON format in noSQL

Tags: json, nosql

I would like to keep a DB of nested groups (For example, a company hierarchy: a manager has managers who manage other managers who manage employees..)

How should one represent this structure as a JSON?

1. Should the name of each manager be a key and the managers below him be an object? (Assume each manager has a unique name)

`{
    "mamanger1": {
        "sub_manager1": {
            ...
        },
        "sub_manager2": {
            ...
        }
    }
}`

2. Or, should the JSON consist of "recursive objects", i.e, a key-value object where key is an identifier and value is an array of same, key-value objects?
   In this case, the key-value pair would be called "name"-"employees".

`{
    "name": "mamanger1",
    "employees": [
        {
            "name": "sub_manager1",
            "employees": [ ... ]
        },
        {
        "name": "sub_manager2",
        "employees": [ ... ]
        },
    ]
}`

- In the first example ,each manager has a unique key (Better performance on search?)
- In the second example, all objects have the save keys (Easier looping?)

Answer (score 0):

In my view you should use the second approach:

Benifits:

1. It is more extensible. You can add more data to manager entity
   later, if needed.
2. Easy looping as you are having field names against each value.
3. Your approach will be more realworld relevant as manager names may or may not be unique.
4. you will not loose in the search performance as you will be having key "name" and values are still unique as per you. Even if it won't be unique, All nosql db store range of values from a key on same node.

When you will ask for details about manager/managers who has name "xyz" the search process is as follows:

1. You hit the api
2. A node receives request
3. Request will be forwarded to a node/nodes having range which xyz belongs to
4. Only data of this node will be scanned and matched ones will be returned.

Also as per me the first approach will be creating as many key as the number of managers. Considering the limited number of nodes, one node will be scanned if you try to get the details for "xyz" as key.

You will get better performance in approach 2 , if you are seaching for "xyz" and "xyz1" in same query. As the string values are close to each other you may get it in the same node(mostly). However, in the first approach there are less chances of getting it on same node as both are not considered neighbors because of different keys all together.